# Why is $G\times G$ mod $\Delta G$ isomorphic to $G$? Particularly, why is this a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. The claim is that $(G\times G)/\Delta G$ is isomorphic to $G$, where $\Delta G = \{(g,g)\in G\times G\mid g\in G\}$.

From my understanding, the map $\varphi:G \times G \rightarrow G$ given by $(g_1,g_2) \mapsto g_1g^{-1}_2$ is supposed to induce the isomorphism because it's clearly surjective and the kernel is the diagonal. But why is this a homomorphism? This is not clear to me except in the case where $G$ is abelian.

Comment: The map is not a homomorphism if the group is not abelian. If $x$ and $y$ do not commute then even though $(x,e)(e,y^{-1}) = (x,y^{-1}) = (e,y^{-1})(x,e)$, the map sends the first product to $xe^{-1}ey = xy$, but it sends the second product to $eyxe^{-1} = yx$, and $xy\neq yx$. In fact, the diagonal is normal if and only if $G$ is abelian: if $x$ and $y$ do not commute, then $(e,y)(x,x)(e,y^{-1}) = (x,yxy^{-1})\notin \Delta G$.

Comment: I'm not an algebraist, what does $\Delta G$ represent?

Comment: @obscurans: The diagonal subgroup, $\Delta G = \{(g,g)\in G\times G\mid g\in G\}$.

Comment: @obscurans The diagonal $\{(g,g)\mid g\in G\,\}$. As commented, it is in general not normal in $G\times G$

Comment: I see. This solves my point of confusion!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct this does not work in general.

In fact, $\Delta G = \{(g,g)\in G\times G\mid g\in G\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G\times G$ if and only if $G$ is abelian: it is clear it is a subgroup and hence normal when $G$ is abelian. And if $x,y\in G$ do not commute, then $(x,x)\in \Delta G$, but
$$ (e,y)(x,x)(e,y)^{-1} = (x,yxy^{-1})\notin \Delta G$$
since $yxy^{-1}=x\implies yx=xy$.

Likewise, the map you mention is a homomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian; this is clear when $G$ is abelian (it is the “sum” of the projection onto the first coordinate, and the composition of the projection onto the second coordinate followed by inversion). When $G$ is not abelian, again if $x,y\in G$ do not commute, then $(x,e)(e,y^{-1}) = (x,y^{—1}) = (e,y^{-1})(x,e)$, but
$$f(x,e)f(e,y^{-1}) = xy \neq yx = f(e,y^{-1})f(x,e).$$

So the statement that $G\times G/\Delta G$ is isomorphic to $G$ only makes sense when $G$ is abelian, in which case the map you give realizes that isomorphism.